# how to input my data into a dictionary from a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a file that has following data format:

```
0
65
88
11
0
11
11
```

I tried to write below code in order to create a dictionary that the keys are the sequences from 1 to EOF and the values are the data in the file:
The code I wrote so far is:

```
hash_1 ={}
#print(hash_1)
file = open('t30.dat','r')
while True:
    data =file.readline()
    if not data:
        break
    print(int(data.strip()))
    #hash_1[int(data.strip())] += 1
```

The problem is the last line that I cannot figure it out how to do this

> hash_1[int(data.strip())] += 1

My desired output should be :

```
hash_1= {1:0,2:65,3:88,4:11,5:0,6:11,7:11}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you are attempting to add 1 to a dictionary value that does not exist. `hash_1` is defined as an empty dictionary, and your code never actually adds items to it, it simply attempts to increase the value of an item that does not exist. For instance, in the first iteration of the loop, `int(data.strip())` evaluates to `0`, meaning it's attempting to execute this:

```
hash_1[0] += 1
```

`hash_1` does not have a value assigned to `0`, thus resulting in an exception.

One solution is to use a counter variable starting at 1 and increased iteration, and assign `hash_1[<counter>]` to the line of data each iteration, like so:

```
hash_1 ={}
#print(hash_1)
file = open('t30.dat','r')
i = 1
while True:
    data =file.readline()
    if not data:
        break
    print(int(data.strip()))
    hash_1[i] = int(data.strip())
    i += 1
print(hash_1)
```

`i` is initially set to 1, and is increased at the end of each iteration of the loop, so the first iteration will assign the key `1` to the first line of data, the second will assign `2` to the next line of data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Functional approach:

```
with open('t30.dat') as f:
    hash_1 = dict(enumerate(map(int, f), start=1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I knew about the enumerate but I was interested to see what is the issue with my own code that I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('t30.dat','r')
lines = file.readlines()
count = 0 #programmers start the count at 0
for line in lines:
    hash_1[count]=int(line)
    count+=1
```

I'm not sure why you don't use an array instead but whatever

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a dictionary comprehension:

```
with open('t30.dat','r') as f:
    hash_1 = dict(enumerate(int(s.strip()) for s in f.read().split("\n"),1))
```